# Wordpress - custom css won't work after updating the page

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend

I have an interesting issue with custom css. I have installed the SiteOrigin Css plugin, and when I give style for a specific class it  will work fine, until I update the page. After updating the page the row's class name or id name will change. 
I am beginner with wordpress, maybe I didn't understand how the custom css works.

Example :
Before updating the page the id name is :

```
#pg-15-10> .panel-row-style
```

After updating the page  the id will change:

```
#pgc-262-10> .panel-row-style
```

Maybe I should target other element, or give a class manually, or add custom css only when the page is finished and no more update will be needed? I uploaded two screenshot about the element.
(This project is on localhost)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3smI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a template for your page and target a unique body class like: .page-template-home

Answer (score 0):

apperently wordpress generates the ids dynamically. Therefore you cannot use them in your css.

I'd recommend using the classname to style your elements.

just use `.panel-row-style` instead

Comment: Yes I was thinking on that, but then will give the style to all my panel row, won't it?

Comment: The css would affect all the rows with the same class, yes. I think Bruno Sousa's answer seems better though.

Comment: I tried, and yes,  applied the style to all my panel